# Arrow(-->) does not show in SQL Server SELECT when use as xml path

Tags: sql-server, for-xml-path

I am trying to get all route path separating with arrow (`-->`). But the arrow (`-->`) does not work, it is shown as `--&gt;`.

```
SELECT 
    vrmd.LocationName + '--> ' 
FROM 
    dbo.tbl_VehicleRouteMapDetail vrmd  
WHERE 
    vrmd.VrmapId = 1
ORDER BY 
    vrmd.VrmapId
FOR XML PATH('')
```

But it's working perfectly this way:

```
DECLARE @Route VARCHAR(MAX)= '' 

SELECT @Route = @Route + vrmd.LocationName + '--> '
FROM dbo.tbl_VehicleRouteMapMaster vrmm
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_VehicleRouteMapDetail vrmd ON vrmd.VrmapId = vrmm.VrmapId
ORDER BY vrmd.VrmapDetailId ASC
```

Why choose first query?

I need to use this query as subquery. In this case second query does not work for me:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(ewva.VehicleId) Allocation, vii.Capacity,
    STUFF((SELECT vrmd.LocationName + '=> ' 
           FROM dbo.tbl_VehicleRouteMapDetail vrmd  
           WHERE vrmd.VrmapId = vrmm.VrmapId
           ORDER BY vrmd.VrmapId
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS name_csv 
FROM  
    dbo.tbl_VehicleInfoInternal vii
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tbl_EmpWiseVehicleAllocation ewva ON ewva.VehicleId = vii.VehicleId
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tbl_VehicleRouteMapMaster vrmm ON vrmm.VehicleId = vii.VehicleId
GROUP BY 
    ewva.VehicleId, vii.Capacity, vrmm.VrmapId
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete result you get and the result you actually want instead. Also, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions. And why do you use `for xml path(...)`?

Comment: It doesn't "work" because you just simply **cannot** use the `>` and `<` characters in XML - since those are used to denote the XML elements. So the `>` characters is **encoded** as `&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as adding the `TYPE` directive to your `FOR XML` clause (docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/type-directive-in-for-xml-queries?view=sql-server-ver15)). This will return the result as an instance of the `XML` type rather than text. Text will have certain characters (e.g. `>` and `<`) translated (`&gt;` and `&lt;`) to fit within an XML element.

```
SELECT 
    vrmd.LocationName + '--> ' 
FROM 
    dbo.tbl_VehicleRouteMapDetail vrmd  
WHERE 
    vrmd.VrmapId = 1
ORDER BY 
    vrmd.VrmapId
FOR XML 
    PATH(''), TYPE
```